# It is possible to register a broadcast receiver in my androidtest case?

Tags: android-testing

My code doest not work, `onReceive` never called.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun receive_broadcast() {
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

        val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
        }

        val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                println("B broadcast received")
                println(intent)
            }
        }
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
            appContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000)
        uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
        Thread.sleep(1000)

        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
            appContext.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
```